# when to use sp_getapplock

Tags: sql-server, concurrency

I have the following situation: stored procedure uses intermittently two tables. I have to execute this sp concurrently (like 50 at the same time). This gives me deadlocks at about 33% cases. 
The question is: is it appropriate to use sp_getapplock here? All I do is add:

```
exec sp_getapplock @Resource = 'resource_name', @LockMode = 'exclusive',@LockTimeout = '60000', @DbPrincipal = 'dbo'
```

as a first command in a transaction and everything seems to be working. Except for concurrency, but that's ok. What's unsettling is that I'm trying to do what database should actually do. Perhaps there are better alternatives or serious drawbacks of this approach?

Comment: Have you already read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191242(v=sql.105).aspx) on minimizing deadlocks and implemented those suggestions where possible?

Comment: yes, I did. The problem is that I don't want to modify the stored procedure. Especially when this approach seems to work, except I'm new to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've probably resolved this now, but in case it helps. Large complex databases under load will almost certainly encounter deadlocks from time to time. It would be too difficult for the database to look ahead to the extent required to be able to determine whether there will be contention for resources later in the process. There are a lot of things you can do to minimise deadlocks, including good indexes, well structured table access and more (plenty of info out there). However there can legitimately be times where you are unable to structure code in such a way that deadlocks are avoided, and making use of `sp_getapplock` is definitely not a bad thing. As you have noted it does cause a bottleneck because you no longer have concurrency. But the benefit of eliminating deadlocks probably more than makes up for it performance wise. Unfortunately for me, I tried something similar in one of my SP's but the call to `sp_getapplock` is itself causing a deadlock - so its not always guaranteed to solve the problem.

Fundamentally it does come down to what you are trying to achieve. But be sure that the more complex database you are working with, the more chance you will need to manually tune aspects of it - it won't do it all for you, and thats why there is still a demand for good database gurus. I would say that unless you have a specific requirement for an SP to be single threaded that using `sp_getapplock` shouldn't be your first attempt at solving an issue - I've only used it 3 times or something. However given your situation I would definitely go with it because it solves your problem, doesn't require you to understand the complex internals of the SP and probably doesn't have any bad side effects. The most likely would be that it might slow down - but doesn't sound like you have noticed that?

Comment: A deadlock is only going to occur if two clients holding locks ask for a lock incompatible with one the other is already holding. Using `sp_getapplock` itself won't cause deadlocks with another client using `sp_getapplock` for the same resource unless this condition is met.

Comment: Right... I allowed for deadlocks being possible with `sp_getapplock`. Was there something you wanted me to know in particular about all this? It seems like your comment is taking the form of a correction, but I can't see where it's correcting anything i said.

Comment: I didn’t say “different resources,” I said “two clients” both asking for a lock for the *same* resource. That resource is identified by the string. Whether you have that string defined in one place or not, if you are getting deadlocked, then more than one caller is trying to get an app lock using the same string. I don’t understand what the misunderstanding is here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199547/discussion-between-dale-burrell-and-erike).